# Why trigger template constructor by accident can be a bad thing?

Tags: c++, templates

EffectiveModernC++ says that template constructor is called instead of the default constructor 
when use like

```
Person p("Nancy");
auto cloneOfP(p);
```

for class:

```
class Person {
public:
  template<typename T>              // perfect forwarding ctor
  explicit Person(T&& n)
  : name(std::forward<T>(n)) {}

  explicit Person(int idx);         // int ctor

  Person(const Person& rhs);        // copy ctor
                                    // (compiler-generated)

  Person(Person&& rhs);             // move ctor
  …                                 // (compiler-generated)

};
```

I understand the missing of const for p make the template one a better candidate. But I do not understand why we do not want this?

Isn't we always want to call the template version since it will forward either (rvalue ref or lvalue).

In other words, what are the case we want to trigger the default(generated) constructor instead?

Comment: One reason you might not want it would be because it fails to compile, like in your example.  `name` is presumably a `std::string`, which can't be constructed from a `Person`.  Whereas the default constructor would have worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

> But I do not understand why we do not want this?

Because it makes the code not compile.  If we complete the example with

```
class Person {
public:
    template<typename T>              // perfect forwarding ctor
    explicit Person(T&& n)
    : name(std::forward<T>(n)) {}

    explicit Person(int idx);         // int ctor

    Person(const Person& rhs);        // copy ctor
                                    // (compiler-generated)

    Person(Person&& rhs);             // move ctor
    std::string name;                               // (compiler-generated)

};
int main()
{
    Person p("Nancy");
    auto cloneOfP(p); 
}
```

We get a compiler error like

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'Person::Person(T&&) [with T = Person&]':
main.cpp:28:20:   required from here
main.cpp:14:30: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(Person&)'
   14 |     : name(std::forward<T>(n)) {}
```

That is why a template like that is a bad thing.  It requires the use of SFINAE to stop it from being called when `T` is of the class type.  That would look like

```
class Person {
public:
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, Person>, bool> = true>              // perfect forwarding ctor
    explicit Person(T&& n)
    : name(std::forward<T>(n)) {}

    explicit Person(int idx);         // int ctor

    Person(const Person& rhs);        // copy ctor
                                    // (compiler-generated)

    Person(Person&& rhs);             // move ctor
    std::string name;                               // (compiler-generated)

};
```

Comment: @N.Shead Yep.  Fixed.  Thanks