# How to make a constructor with unknown number of parameters?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates, constructor

I'm writing a geometry class **Polygon** which has a private field **std::vector points** where Point:

```
struct Point {
    double x,y;
}
```

I need to construct a polygon with an unknown number of points using templates.

I've tried

```
template<Point &head, Point &...tail>
Polygon() {
    this->points.push_back(head);
    Polygon(tail...);
}
```

But when calling `Polygon polygon = Polygon(Point(1, 4), Point(14.5, -15), Point(0, 0.0));`,  it fails with

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Polygon'

What's the problem and how to fix it? I'm using **C++14**

Comment: Template arguments are not the same as function arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you provide some more explanation and a solution to my problem, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want:

```
struct Point {
    double x,y;
};

struct Polygon {
private:
    std::vector<Point> v;
public:
    template<class ... Points>
    Polygon(Points&& ... points) : v{std::forward<Points>(points)...} {}
};
```

all items of parameters pack are expanded to *vector* constructor overload taking initalizer list.

and the call of ctor:

```
Polygon p = Polygon(Point{1,2},Point{2,3},Point{3,4});
```

---

EDIT

As NathanOliver mentioned in the comment, some SFINAE could be added to provide that variadic constructor is called only if all passed arguments are instances of `Point`.

```
template<
    class ... Points, 
    std::enable_if_t< std::conjunction_v< std::is_same<Point,std::decay_t<Points> >... > >* = nullptr 
>
Polygon(Points&& ... points) : v{std::forward<Points>(points)...} {}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/AMSqYR)

Comment: Could you explain what && does? Or where I can read shortly about it?

Comment: It is called *forwarding reference*, you could read about it for example here: https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Comment: [Pro Tip] Add a constraint (some SFINAE) to the constructor to make it less greedy.  Right now it will have some unintended consequences. [See this for moer information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645868/why-trigger-template-constructor-by-accident-can-be-a-bad-thing/60645936#60645936)

Comment: @MarkTiukov Answer was edited, SFINAE was used to disable some unexpected behaviour when dealing for example with copy constructors.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct for your case. Here a more general approach where you cant just '"coincidentally" use the vector constructor. Also usefull if you want to do any other operation on each element.

```
class Polygon
{
public:

    Polygon() = default;

    template<typename ...Points>
    Polygon(Points&&... points)
    {
        add(std::forward<Points>(points)...);
    }

    template<typename ...Tail>
    Polygon& add(Point& main, Tail&&... tail)
    {
        add(main);
        add(std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
        return *this;
    }

    Polygon& add(Point& main)
    {
        points.push_back(main);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Point> points;
};
```

Comment: Why do you make add(Point& main) return Polygon& instead of void? For future purposes?

Comment: Yes, for future purposes.